# WP8 performance in multithread XNA game

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, xna

I'm working on multithreaded game and targeting wp7 and wp8. I'm using background threads for network comunication and got stuck on problem that wp8 has huge perfomapnce issue when i have 3-4 background threads. Fps drops, for example if you touch rectangle and move it around screen with your finger it will move discrete not smoothly. But on wp7 all works smoothly and perfect. Whats wrong with multithreading in wp8? Are there any good practices to achieve good perfomance? Tested on lumia 920 and htc hd7

**Workaround**
Looks like promblem with new wp8 software update, but have no other device to test.

Comment: How are you creating your thread? What exactly are you doing inside?

Comment: i've tried `BackgroundWorker`, `ThreadPool`, `Thread` classes the result always the same. For example enought to get spikes is to create `BackgroundWorker` in `OnActivated` event and this worker has inside infinite while loop and 3-4 simple if\else statements

Comment: You should use a Thread, not a BackgroundWorker. And do you still have the issue on WP8 if you remove the if/else statements and just keep the infinite loop (without doing anything inside)?

Comment: I've just find out that wp8 works faster in debug mode, and lags while  app launched without debugger. And this single thread now doesn't affect on perfomance. But still 3-4 background threads bring huge fps drop on wp8 and all fine on wp7